# RegExp for required keywords?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, find

I've got a system in C# where by a set of keywords are required.  Two fields have to be checked if the keywords exist.

Initially I wrote a foreach loop to go through each keyword, then cycle through the results and check.  However, this is somewhat inefficient, as on check, I would like to see if any of the keywords exist in a given string, rather than one by one.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

((keyword1)|(keyword2)|(keyword3))

Im not sure exactly how c# does regex but this should match and return matches.

You can test regexes [here](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: I believe OP's question is more on loops than regex.

Answer (score 2):

Does this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698596/regex-to-match-multiple-strings) match what you are trying to do?

The answer shows you how to match multiple possible words in one go with a regex

Answer (score 1):

If you are on c# 3.5+ try this

```
        Regex r1 = new Regex("MyKeywordRegex");
        IEnumerable<MyResultClass> results = GetMyResults();
        var myFilteredResults = results.Any(a => (r1.IsMatch(a.Field)));
```

Comment: You don't need two regexs. One regex can check for the existence of both/all words.

Comment: Either I'm going mad or you edited your question as I was making that comment :)

Comment: @Russell - I was updating the code :). Good catch though, thanks.

Comment: I'd give you and kniteli an upvote but apparently I'm out of votes today. The one regex is the correct thing to do though.