# Java Pattern regex whole word match

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to match a keyword with following string

"abc,pqr(1),xyz"

It will be succesfull match if the whole one word matched for e.g. "par" or "abc" or "xyz"

Can anyone please help me in creating regex for this match ?

```
String text    = "hello, hellos(1),bye";
    String keyword = "account";
    String patternString = "["+ keyword + "]";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    boolean matches = matcher.matches();

    System.out.println("matches = " + matches);
```

Comment: there are some very usefull resources on the net. Like [regex testers](https://regex101.com/) that give you explanation as you write your regex. Pretty nice when you want to learn how to use it.

Comment: You could try replacing `"[" + keyword + "]"` with `"\\b" + keyword + "\\b"` and that should work.

Comment: @Andrevin is right, but be aware that: A) it will also find words inside the parenthesis B) if compound words are allowed between commas then either part can match C) if there are hyphens in words, those will also be treated as word barriers (`\b`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to match multiple strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698596/regex-to-match-multiple-strings)

Answer (score 0):

This Should Work.

```
([a-zA-Z]+)
```

Input:

```
"abc,pqr(1),xyz"
```

Output:

```
abc
pqr
xyz
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/Us6G3X/2

Comment: Thanks, but it will match if my keyword has alphabets or not 
what I want is :
my keyword = hello

match string = "hello, hellos(0),bye"

it should only match to hello 
not to hellos also not to hell